# XID issues with back button and reload

Tags: xid

Running 2.7.3 with secure forms, everything works fine passing the xid_hash etc... until somebody clicks the back button or tries to reload after submitting a form.

It's the usual issue of it trying to reuse the same xid, but I can't refresh the xid as they're just clicking back.

I notice in the 2.8 changelog developers section it's deprecated a load of xid functions, do we know if this somehow fixes this?

Comment: I haven't tested anything, but look at the following questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button and http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14490/xid-issue-with-ajax-based-checkout-ct?rq=1. Use javascript to detect if the page is stale, and then make an AJAX call to refresh the XID field.

Comment: @nageeb Thanks for the links - I'd seen one but not the other. I can't really see this as a solution though. There are a high percentage of users that rely on the back button ([see here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/do-users-understand-the-browser-back-button)) it seems ridiculous that EE would add in a feature that essentially breaks it on any number of interactions. We shouldn't have to rely on js to work around it.

Comment: Agreed.  I've always found EE's XID feature to cause more headaches than the problem it was designed to 'solve'.

Answer (score 1):

We have an add-on for this that is very simple to use and will allow you to put a plugin tag under your form {exp:formrefresher} and if that template is loaded via the back button it will refresh the page, and will refresh your form with a new XID to remove the users frustration on repeated form submissions with errors do to expired XID.

Form Refresher -> https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/form-refresher